# what is the proplem in super method?

Tags: dart, super

I have a problem in this code with dart:

```
void main() {
    Mobile OPPO = Mobile(
        color: 'yellow',
        price: 5500,
    );

    OPPO.printColor();
    OPPO.printPrice();
}

class Devices {
    String? color;
    int? price;
}

class Mobile extends Devices {
    Mobile({
        String? color,
        int? price,
    }) : super(color=color, price=price);

    void printColor() {
        print(color);
    }

    void printPrice() {
        print(price);
    }
}
```

> lib/Test%20oop.dart:19:13: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
> Try removing the extra positional arguments.
> }) : super(color=color, price=price);
> ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `Devices` missing constructor, dart meaning defaut `Devices()` so it have no arguments but you passing 2. To fix this, create `Devices` contructor with 2 arguments.

**Addtional**: super using `:` not `=`.

[image]

Comment: With Dart 2.17, the `Mobile` constructor can now be just `Mobile({super.color, super.price});`.